# Animated icon for Winforms Treeview?

Tags: winforms, treeview, icons

I'd like to show a "Loading" icon as each node of a treeview is waiting to be loaded.  I'm picturing the Win 7 waiting circle that spins, but any animated icon would work.  Is this possible with the standard Winforms treeview?

I'm on VS 2010, Win 7/64, .NET 3.5.  App needs to run on XP/32 as well.

Comment: Alter the TreeNode.ImageIndex property with a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard treeview does not support animated cursors or gifs (.cur or .ani; .gif).  You can use a timer and swap out the nodes' icon to create your own animation.